# Can I let PostgreSQL report the offending rows when a multi-row INSERT fails?

Tags: postgresql, insert, error-handling

When inserting multiple rows into a table by a single `INSERT INTO` invocation, and the `INSERT` statement fails due to reasons specific to some individual rows (e.g. a value has the wrong type for the target column, or a `NOT NULL` constraint is violated), can I let PostgreSQL report the content of the offending rows?

For `UNIQUE` constraint or exclusion constraint violation errors, it seems I could use the [`ON CONFLICT` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to access the offending rows, but is there something similar for other row-specific violations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When inserting multiple rows

Not sure what exactly you mean. It should already report the content of the offending rows.

```
# CREATE TABLE foo ( x int );
-- Two rows that work.
# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT 0 2
-- Three rows that explode.
# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2), ('a');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "a"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2), ('a');
                                          ^
```

What more content are you looking for?

Comment: I've [asked a new question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168160/120405) instead of editing this one, so as not to invalidate this existing answer.